# How to send 1 million of push notification (APNS) within few second using PushSharp as webservice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

to do that i made a web service to send push (by referencing PushSharp library). I request web service through my web application. i retrieve list of device token from database(using web application) send to web service using for loop to send push. and get result/exception for each one. This process is very slow and take long long time to send notification. If anybody suggest me to what should i do i will be grateful to you.

```
public ActionResult SendNowToken(int certificateInfoId, string message, string certificate, int badgeNo, int pushtype, string password, string countryJsonString)
    {
        if (IsPushParameterValid(certificateInfoId, message, certificate, badgeNo, pushtype, password, countryJsonString))
        {
            var countryObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Country>(countryJsonString);
            var errorList = new List<ErrorList>();
            byte[] certificatePath = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/certificate/" + certificate));
            foreach (var aDeviceToken in countryObject.DeviceTokens)
            {
                try
                {
                    var serviceClient = new PushServiceSoapClient();
                    string serviceResult = serviceClient.SendPushNotification(message, badgeNo, pushtype, aDeviceToken.Token, certificatePath, password);

                    if (serviceResult != "Sent Notification")
                    {
                        var delimiters = new[] { ' ' };
                        string[] errorResult = serviceResult.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        string errorMessage = ConvertErrorCodeToErrorMessage(errorResult[0]);
                        var error = new ErrorList
                        {
                            CountryName = countryObject.CountryName,
                            ErrorTime = DateTime.Now,
                            ErrorMessage = errorMessage,
                            Token = aDeviceToken.Token
                        };
                        errorList.Add(error);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var error = new ErrorList
                     {
                         CountryName = countryObject.CountryName,
                         ErrorTime = DateTime.Now,
                         ErrorMessage = ex.Message,
                         Token = aDeviceToken.Token
                     };
                    errorList.Add(error);
                }
            }
            if (errorList.Count != 0)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Push Notification does not send to country... ";
                return PartialView("_SendAllError", errorList.ToList());
            }
            errorList.Clear();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Build a windows service and use multiple threads to send out push notifications.

Comment: Is windows service possible to integrate in web application?

Comment: From the question you already have a web service so you can call your web service from windows service and that would solve it.

Comment: I also mentioned web service called by web application. now i don't know what should i do. though I'm not enough skilled.